# Printing subscript in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3, subscript

In Python 3.3, is there any way to make a part of text in a string subscript when printed?

e.g. H₂ (H and then a subscript 2)

Comment: Do you mean in plain text, or HTML, or something else? Also, are you only interested in subscripting numerals?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If all you care about are digits, you can use the [`str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) methods:

```
example_string = "A0B1C2D3E4F5G6H7I8J9"

SUB = str.maketrans("0123456789", "₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉")
SUP = str.maketrans("0123456789", "⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹")

print(example_string.translate(SUP))
print(example_string.translate(SUB))
```

Which will output:

```
A⁰B¹C²D³E⁴F⁵G⁶H⁷I⁸J⁹
A₀B₁C₂D₃E₄F₅G₆H₇I₈J₉
```

Note that this won't work in Python 2 - see [Python 2 maketrans() function doesn't work with Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30108869) for an explanation of why that's the case, and how to work around it.

Comment: +1. @Sam: To emphasize, the only subscript that can directly be done like this requires the existence of the special characters (in Unicode). This way, the 2 and 4 in `'H₂SO₄'` are actually different characters than 2 and 4. Yet, it is rather unusual way to implement the subscript and superscript. As Bakuriu mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24391972/1346705, the usual way is to use something more than a viewer capable to display Unicode characters.

Comment: This code is great in Python 3 but breaks in Python 2: [Python 2 maketrans() function doesn't work with Unicode: “the arguments are different lengths” when they actually are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108869/python-maketrans-function-doesnt-work-because-the-arguments-are-different-len)

Answer (score 34):

The output performed on the console is simple text. If the terminal supports unicode (most do nowadays) you can use [unicode's subscripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts). (e.g H₂) Namely the subscripts are in the ranges:

- 0x208N for numbers, `+`, `-`,  `=`, `(`, `)` (`N` goes from `0` to `F`)
- 0x209N for letters

For example:

```
In [6]: print(u'H\u2082O\u2082')
H₂O₂
```

For more complex output you must use a markup language (e.g. HTML) or a typesetting language (e.g. LaTeX).

Comment: They end up upside down twos

Comment: @Sam ? No. The subscript `2` is just a small `2` put a bit lower.

Comment: 0x209N isn't the full letter range. It's just a, e, o, x then an upside-down e.

Answer (score 19):

Using code like this works too:

```
print('\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER PI}r\N{SUPERSCRIPT TWO}')
print('\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER THETA}r\N{SUBSCRIPT TWO}')
```

The output being:

```
πr²
Θ₂
```

Note that this works on Python versions 3.3 and higher only. Unicode formatting.

Comment: Please help me in understanding the use of `\N{}` in python

Comment: This worked for me, but still need to search for subscript code for plus sign

Comment: @tbhaxor \N{name} is an escape sequence. 
Meaning: Character named name in the Unicode database (Unicode only)

Answer (score 16):

If you want to use it on the axes of a plot you can do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1])
plt.ylabel(r'$H_{2}$')
plt.show()
```

which gives

[image]

Details on the Tex markup language and how to use it in matplotlib can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html).

Comment: If you want to combine it with f string, you can use something like `fr'$i_{str(idx)}$'`.

Answer (score 2):

By using this code you can use alphabets on the superscript and subscript
    In This code
              format() is Function and in Format function ('\unicode')

By using this table ([Unicode subscripts and superscripts on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)) you can give suitable unicode to the suitable one

you can use superscript and sub script

```
"10{}".format('\u00B2')  # superscript 2
```

Comment: Why would you use `format` here? Just `"10\u00B2"` works fine.