# Python 2 maketrans() function doesn't work with Unicode: "the arguments are different lengths" when they actually are

Tags: python, string, unicode, python-2.x, translate

[Python 2]
    SUB = string.maketrans("0123456789","₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉")

this code produces the error:

```
ValueError: maketrans arguments must have same length
```

I am unsure why this occurs because the strings are the same length. My only idea is that the subscript text length is somehow different than standard size characters but I don't know how to get around this.

Comment: Works fine in Python 3 (which does have much nicer unicode support anyway), is that an option for you?

Comment: currently I'm running python 2.7 but I will be sure to take a look at Python 3

Comment: That Python 3 code is from @ZeroPiraeus' neat answer to ["Printing subscript in python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391892/printing-subscript-in-python/24392215#24392215)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, the arguments are not the same length:

```
>>> len("0123456789")
10
>>> len("₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉")
30
```

You are trying to pass in *encoded data*; I used UTF-8 here, where each digit is encoded to 3 bytes each.

You cannot use `str.translate()` to map ASCII bytes to UTF-8 byte sequences. Decode your string to `unicode` and use the slightly different `unicode.translate()` method; it takes a *dictionary* instead:

```
nummap = {ord(c): ord(t) for c, t in zip(u"0123456789", u"₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉")}
```

This creates a dictionary mapping Unicode codepoints (integers), which you can then use on a *Unicode* string:

```
>>> nummap = {ord(c): ord(t) for c, t in zip(u"0123456789", u"₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉")}
>>> u'99 bottles of beer on the wall'.translate(nummap)
u'\u2089\u2089 bottles of beer on the wall'
>>> print u'99 bottles of beer on the wall'.translate(nummap)
₉₉ bottles of beer on the wall
```

You can then encode the output to UTF-8 again if you so wish.

From the [method documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

> For Unicode objects, the `translate()` method does not accept the optional *deletechars* argument. Instead, it returns a copy of the *s* where all characters have been mapped through the given translation table which must be a mapping of Unicode ordinals to Unicode ordinals, Unicode strings or `None`. Unmapped characters are left untouched. Characters mapped to `None` are deleted.

Comment: is there any other way to get subscript characters in python? or even a way to over come this length difference

Comment: Aaron: this would not be a limitation of Python ... but rather it's an implication of the differences between ASCII and Unicode.  There are no "subscript characters" in ASCII.  The implications of using *Unicode* characters is that Python cannot treat such characters as if they were ASCII --- any attempt to do so may work for some cases but will break for others.

Comment: @Martijn Where did you get 30? I get either 10 or "Unsupported characters in input", depending on where I try it.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: using the interactive interpreter in a terminal configured for UTF-8 use.

Comment: Only in Python 2. The length is 30 in Python 2 and 10 in Python 3. OP's code works fine in Python 3.

Comment: @smci exactly; you’ll only see this specific error in Python 2 because these are byte strings. That's why the question is tagged with the [tag:python-2.x] tag.