# Weird behavoir with casting int

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am using Python 3.6.3 and I encounter a weird behavior from `int()` and `isdigit()` with the following code:

```
s = "..... not less than 66²/ 3 % of ......"
total = 0
for c in s:
    if c.isdigit():
        total += int(c)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '²'
```

I understand the bug and I know that I can skip the error with `try catch`. My question is that if `isdigit()` return true then the char\string should be cast without error or `isdigit()` should return false. Otherwise said `int()` and `isdigit()` should be coherent.

Comment: Actually, [`isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) is documented to work in exactly this case

Comment: This is so unbelievable that it feels like a bug but it actually makes sense. Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891070/whats-the-difference-between-str-isdigit-isnumeric-and-isdecimal-in-python) (kind of)

Comment: Why do you believe this to be the case? As noted, the documentation explicitly states otherwise.

Comment: Don't know if it's viable but technically I guess you could use a regex to turn superscripts to `**n` then your algorithm my be easier to implement. Or even just in the case of superscripts use pythonic exponential notation. `**n`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I hold my hands up as guilty for having taken this method on face value. At least for me, it was too easy to feel I implicitly knew what it did; the corner case being that it wouldn't work with negative numbers for `all()` etc. Considering the rapid upvotes, I have a feeling there's a lot of code out there than can be crashed with this, explicitly documented or not :P

Comment: I mean technically in human terms it is a "number"... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @roganjosh well, fundamentally, the correct approach is to use `try-except` here, IMO not relying on assumptions about how characters are classed (especially when you factor in unicode characters)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Devil's advocate being, what if you _wanted_ that 2 to be an integer? That's what's going on in the comments under the answer.

Comment: why not allow `2√(π²)/π` as a valid int then. Where does it stop.

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte well considering pi is not an integer, then I could safely say that this out of the realms of reasonable, even `'1.234'` can't be cast to `int` directly (but maybe a float :P ). I get the point you're making, though.

Comment: Good luck with your human language interpreter then... It look like [it exists](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2√(π²)%2Fπ)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly [as documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

> `str.isdigit()` Return true if all characters in the string are digits
>   and there is at least one character, false otherwise. Digits include
>   decimal characters and digits that need special handling, such as the
>   compatibility superscript digits. This covers digits which cannot be
>   used to form numbers in base 10, like the Kharosthi numbers. Formally,
>   a digit is a character that has the property value Numeric_Type=Digit
>   or Numeric_Type=Decimal.

Comment: This makes it clear ... but it's very annoying ...  even I tried with re.match([0-9]+, c) and I still get the same behavior ... is there a method that rejects those digits, or a method that can cast them?

Comment: `re.match([0-9]+, c)` should work `c in "1234567890"` too as well as `c.isdecimal()`

Comment: I like where @Gha93 is headed by asking if there could be a replacement for using `int` here there's gotta be a way to marry `isdigit` with a corresponding method.

Comment: @Gha93 it depends what you want to do, but `all(c in '1234567890' for c in '66²')` might suffice

Comment: @Jaba https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391892/printing-subscript-in-python? But then I'm not sure how to use on floats.

Comment: yep your are right re.match works

Comment: Right, We should make it clear that `try: int(s); catch ValueError:` is the correct way of handling this. Some people don't like `try/catch` but it is the most Pythonic way.

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte It really depends what they want to do, `int('-3')` is valid of course but not all digits

Comment: `if int(s) < 0: raise ValueError("the input number should be a positive integer")`

Comment: the key idea is what the mean of isdigit() returning true saying yes it's  a 'number' but you can't always cast it.

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte I think the mantra of "ask forgiveness not permission" is the better option in most situations. A tight loop where exceptions are expected to be common (most characters in that string aren't decimals) is usually not one of them.